# can the simulator_gazebo of ROS do same job as gazebo under ubuntu?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am learning `simulator_gazebo` of ROS, but it is not same with gazebo, when I follow the tutorial of gazebo, I can not continue to do the example, so ,is the `simulator_gazebo` same to gazebo? and its tutorial is same to gazebo? can it do same job like gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/180/can-the-simulator_gazebo-of-ros--do-same-job-as-gazebo-under-ubuntu?/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ROS's simulator_gazebo is moving towards using system install of gazebo.  The current outstanding issue is found [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/357/prepare-tic-toc-from-old-pre-gazebo-10-xml)

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It can do the same job, however the one under ROS uses a different model structure URDF(is beeing deprecated though). Whereas current gazebo uses *.SDF. Some standard settings might be different. However the main difference is that ROS comes with a large library of other robotics tools, and gazebo plugins, which you can couple to gazebo.
Hence controlling your robots in under ROS is somewhat simpler(using nodes, services etc.), as what most people need is already programmed by others and added to the package. I prefer just plain gazebo, as i have no use for the ROS control.

---

Originally posted by [Erik Stoltenborg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/77/erik-stoltenborg/) with karma: 86 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2012-11-09**:
thanks a lot, I find this question, and I try to using plain gazebo, because the turorial of simulator_gazebo is too less